# Access attribute ID from asp:Dropdown but display the attribute only c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, database

I am trying to build a simple web application for my final year project at uni.

I have managed to set up an SQL database using vs2012. I have a page which is trying to add stock to the "Stock" table of the database.

I have encountered a problem when I have created an asp:DropDownList, I have chosen the data source from the table "Clients" (this has information in it) and all is displaying nicely.

However in my table "Stock" I have a foreign key as "ClientID" this is for the user to select who the stock belongs to.

I have a problem accessing the ID of the person i am clicking on. Here is how I am going about doing it.

clsStock

```
private int ClientID;

public int ClientIDRecord
{
   get
   {
     return ClientID;
   }
   set
   {
     ClientID = value;
   }
}

public void saveStockInformation()
{
            clsLabelsDataConduit stockDetails = new clsLabelsDataConduit();
            stockDetails.Execute("sprocTableStock_GetAll");
             stockDetails.NewRecord["ClientID"] = clientIDRecord;
}
```

addstock.aspx.cs

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelsClassLib.clsStock stockData = new LabelsClassLib.clsStock();
        stockData.clientIDRecord = drpClientName.SelectedIndex;
        stockData.saveStockInformation();
}
```

My SQL Tables:
Clients:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients] (
    [ClientID]           INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]          VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [LastName]           VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [ClientAddressLine1] VARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
    [ClientAddressLine2] VARCHAR (30)  NULL,
    [Town]               VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [County]             VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [Postcode]           VARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
    [MobileNumber]       VARCHAR (12)  NOT NULL,
    [HomeNumber]         VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [EmailAddress]       VARCHAR (320) NOT NULL,
    [DateAddedToSystem]  ROWVERSION    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ClientID] ASC)
);
```

Stock table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stock] (
    [StockID]           INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientID]          INT          NOT NULL,
    [ItemTypeID]        INT          NOT NULL,
    [ItemName]          VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    [ImageOfItem]       IMAGE        NULL,
    [DateAddedToSystem] DATE         NULL,
    [DateSold]          DATE         NULL,
    [DatePurchased]     DATE         NULL,
    [ItemDescription]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [RetailPrice]       MONEY        NULL,
    [Quantity ]         SMALLINT     NULL,
    [ItemSold]          VARCHAR (3)  NULL,
    [Designer]          VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [PurchasePrice]     MONEY        NULL,
    [ItemColour]        VARCHAR (20) NULL,
    [ItemSize]          INT          NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StockID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ClientID] FOREIGN KEY ([ClientID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemType] FOREIGN KEY ([ItemTypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ItemTypes] ([ItemTypeID])
);
```

I feel like I know and understand the problem but I don't know how to remedy this issue, if any one could help it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related of how you get the value from your dropdown list instead of `stockData.clientIDRecord = drpClientName.SelectedIndex`; should be

```
stockData.clientIDRecord = drpClientName.SelectedValue;
```

It also depends on how you made the databinding and specified wich property will be stored as value in the dropdown list.

```
drpClientName.DataValueField ="ClientID"
```